# useEffect cleanup not being called on browser back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v5.1 and am trying to clear a session variable when navigating to a different page. If I click a link on the page, the cleanup callback is fired, however, if I use the browser back button, the route changes but the cleanup callback is not fired.

I would really rather not have to hook into react-router's location/routes/etc as this would be a really simple way to accomplish what I am trying to do AND I am obviously not understanding what is going on with useEffect so it would be great to get a better handle on that.

Thanks!

```
const LinkProvider: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation
  useEffect(() => {
    return (): void => {
      console.log('unmount');
      sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (<div></div>)
}
```

I have also tried

```
const LinkProvider: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return (): void => {
      console.log('unmount');
      sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (<div></div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code. I'm wondering what was the problem in your code. 
Did you use 'react-router' instead of 'react-router-dom'?

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";
import ProfilePage from "./components/ProfilePage";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/"} exact>
          <LandingPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile">
          <ProfilePage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

components/ProfilePage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ProfilePage = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Profile page unmount");
      sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, This is the home page</h1>
      <Link to="/">Go to Landing</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

components/LandingPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LandingPage = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Landing page unmount");
      sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, This is the home page</h1>
      <Link to="/profile">Go to Profile</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Here is the link to codesandbox. It works fine.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-shaw-7bofu

Comment: Thanks @TopW3. I'm not sure exactly what the problem was but I built it back up from your example and it's working now!